# How can I force an old-style alt-tab menu programatically in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi

If you press Alt+Tab in the computer game "League of Legends", the old Alt+Tab dialog window known from older Windows versions is shown:

[image: Old-style alt-teb menu]

(You can see a screen shot of the full screen here: https://i.imgur.com/vnbSz8L.png.)

I'd like to know if it is possible to write an own application that behaves the same way using the Windows API, so the dialog window shown in the screen shot is shown if I press Alt+Tab.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. this is probably question for a Stack Overflow site and depends on the programming language.

At least I can at least tell you how to show the old switcher:

1. Press and hold the left or right Alt key
2. Tap and release the other Alt key on your keyboard
3. Press Tab

Voila!

Alternatively you can force old style through the registry:

1. Open regedit HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
2. Create a new 32-bit DWORD on the right-hand side, give it the name AltTabSettings with value "1"

Voila 2! :)

Comment: Thanks but I would like to know how to achieve this programatically, I posted on Stack Overflow but a few grumpy moderators deemed it off-topic

Comment: I will ask for you there.. just what language should it be, C#?

Comment: Yes C# would be perfect

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62266503/c-sharp-force-using-xp-style-alt-tab-switcher